# How can I have an Express/Connect route that doesn't update session

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I'm building a single-page javascript app that talks to Express on the back end.  At various points in the app, we interact with the back end, updating the session.  The session expiration is relatively short for security reasons.

In it, I'd like to warn the user that the session might be expiring, if they've been idle for a long time and have not made any transactions with the back end.

I'd like to have an Express "heartbeat" route that returns how long the session has remaining (session.maxAge), but I don't want it to refresh the session expiration.

The connect.session code automatically refreshes the session at the end of a request.

I'm looking for a way to have access to the session to fetch the maxAge, but not have it updated.

Comment: Have you considered using http://socket.io ?

Comment: Heh, that's actually what I'm using.  But, socket.io + cluster + redisstore + xhr_polling = complete fail (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/939).  So, I'm looking for an old school workaround.  Also - touching the session through socket.io doesn't update the expire on the cookie - so the redis/cookie expires become divergent until a real request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be modifying your SessionStore manually to not modify the session expiration when coming from a specific route (req.url).

Look for the part of your sessionStore that calls Session.touch().